# Access Samsung S9 without providing Sim card pin code, no code otherwise to unlock it

Tags: samsung, sim-card

My girlfriends mother recently passed away. She wants to gain access to her mother's phone but unluckily it was out of power when she got it. The phone does not normally need any kind of code to unlock it but since it was powered down we need to provide the Sim code which we have not found yet.

I am wondering what will happen if we simply remove the SIM-card? I am uneasy to try if that would lock it further or that we need to provide the puk code instead. She just wants to be able to access it.

Thankful for any answers that might help.

Comment: You can simply remove the SIM card then you don't need the PIN anymore. Removing it has no effect on the phone except from the telephony and cellular internet access.

Comment: Sadly upon removing the Sim card it asked for a code :( Any ideas what to do next? I will call the cell provider tomorrow and Samsung to see what their policies on this are, any tips in the mean time? Also, if the cell provider gives us the pin code for the Sim, will it still ask for still extra code?

Comment: Most likely that is the lock screen PIN which is always asked. If aSIM card is inserted it just asks for the SIM pin first.

Comment: They already said it's the SIM card pin, not the lock screen PIN.